# Is there a way the receive the value of a specific classical register after simulation?

Tags: qiskit, simulation

I have several classical registers in my circuit that I'm simulating using qiskit, and I'm looking for a way to access the simulation results of a subset of them, desirably according to their name.

Currently, I'm taking the raw results of the simulation, and then doing some string manipulation to get the information I need, for that I need to know the location of my registers in the result, which is very inconvenient.

```
r = execute(qc, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),noise_model=noise_model, shots=shots, memory=True).result()
all_mes = r.get_memory()
for mes in all_mes:
    print("".join(mes.split(" ")[1:3]))
```

Do you know of a simpler and more convenient way to do it?

Comment: You can't change the code not to measure the bits you don't care about?

Comment: The "extra" measurements come from projective measurements I perform and do conditional operations according to these measurements. So I can't remove them.